# jquery regular expression for 2-letter, 3-letter numbers and 3 digits

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have a text input inside form. I'm using Jquery to validate the input. Only 2-letter, 3-letter, 3-digit inputs will be accepted. How can I create regular expression for this?

Comment: By the way, here is a great regex tester [link](http://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: can you be more clear with your question.do you want to check for minimum 2 letters,3 numbers

Comment: Can you clarify whether `a2c` is a valid string?

Answer (score 2):

This is the regexp you're looking for:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{3})$
```

[image: Regular expression image]

**Valid data sample:**

- ab
- abc
- 123

**Invalid data sample:**

- a
- abcd
- 12
- 1234
- a2c *(based on how I understood your question)*

**[You can test this regexp on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/o3TbjgkU_B7_by8j)** *(thanks to [Arnaud Christ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087711/arnaud-christ) for the link).*